# Is this regular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets suppose, that for *k*:

$A^k=I$ , k is natural number:

Does it mean that matrix A is regular?

I think yes. Every regular matrix is invertible:

$AA^{-1}=I$

$A^k=I$

then
$A^k=AA^{-1}$

Is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: It is better to use the determinant. Then you can multiply $A^k=I$ by $A^{-1}$ to obtain an explicit expression for the inverse: $A^{-1}=A^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right since, for example:

$$1=\det I=\det A^k=\left(\det A\right)^k\implies \det A \neq0\iff A\;\;\text{is invertible}$$